# squid proxy from localhost configs

Tags: squid

I'm trying to give a remote machine (that I can ssh to) access to the internet through my local machine.

Currently, I've set up a squid server locally, with the intent of using a reverse tunnel a la http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1765935

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the local proxy to work, on account of ignorance of how proxy-ing works.

Currently:

squid3 proxy running locally port 3128.  `$nmap localhost` confirms: `3128/tcp open  squid-http`

iptables set to allow access to port 3128 only from localhost: https://serverfault.com/questions/247176/iptables-only-allow-localhost-access

squid conf unaltered.

testing locally: `$export http_proxy=localhost:3128`

testing locally: `$lynx google.com`

failure.

Any thoughts?

Comment: add `$export https_proxy=localhost:3128`

Answer (score 0):

Try;

Add

> $export https_proxy=localhost:3128
>
> $lynx google.com

Google redirect to https